# Set Pidgin Status from Outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pidgin

Is there a way to set the Pidgin status from Outlook's calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Currently no. Maybe you could write an app that does that. It would be awesome!

Comment: What makes you so sure there isn't? This is not really a useful answer.

Comment: As someone that hangs out in the Pidgin developer mailing list, I can confirm there is no such feature.  It would require someone write a plugin for MS Office that sends a message externally.

Comment: Plugin request in bugtracker: https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/12165

Comment: Would [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sipe/) help?

Answer (score 0):

What Jérõme suggested in a comment is working for me: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sipe/

To explain, I just did this:

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin pidgin-sipe
```

Then I configured everything in Pidgin to point to my office 365 account and it works like a charm ;)